# How to design a database for an eCommerce website using Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, redis

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to build an eCommerce website, but I'm facing a problem of storing data of products that don't share the same attributes. I'm wondering which database technologies to use and how design database in such way that I could store different products attributes without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Django is good with RDB (Relationals Data Bases).

Dealing with undetermined data, you need to use JSON storage format because you don't know what attributes have the model. Non-Relationals Data Bases are good for that, but, RDB isn't. You can use MongoDB for storage that JSON info, but there born a new question:

**When to use MongoDB with Django?**

**Short Answer: You don't.**

Source: [when to use mongodb with django](https://www.pydanny.com/when-to-use-mongodb-with-django.html)

You can use Postgresql JSON field implementation in Django.

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):

    metadata = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```